# how to force non-www when person visits website store

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, opencart

I have a script on my website that is a module addon for opencart. I tried working with the developer but this is what he told me.

> The browser will block the ajax request as a cross domain request.
>   This is just how scripts and browsers work it has nothing to do with
>   my mod. You need to put a redirect in your .htaccess to make sure that
>   people always wind up on the proper domain non-www.

and

> they are are ajax requests. I'm not sure how you would enable them for
>   cross domain support.

The issue is pretty much when I load my website, i have a script. a car make, model, year chooser, it works for some people and not for others. I realized it was with the www. infront of the domain. When the www. is removed it works for everyone, when it is added it stops working for everyone.

Is there a way to force non-www. on my website store directory **/store/**

I have tried this but it says an error

> The page isn't redirecting properly Browser has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to force non-www. on my website store directory /store/

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^store(/.*)?$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: And to do it for the whole website, no matter what directory I would remove the **store** part?

Comment: Yes that's correct, for that use: `RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]` in last line.